# Visual Studio 2008 project not building after beign moved to a new machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build

I moved one of my VS projects (C#) from one machine to another (SVN checkout) and when I'm trying to build it there I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions 
property for more information.
```

That doesn't give too much information about the nature of the problem. There were no problems building the same checkout on other machines. All of the machines I'm building this project are using the same version of VS 2008 SP1 and .NET 3.5SP1. Can anyone give me some clues where should I look for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd enable the fusion log (part of the .Net SDK), then use the viewer to check for binding problems - may even be that VS needs repairing...

[Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: This tools works on run time. I cannot build my app so that won't help me too much.

Comment: Actually, it'll display the binding errors in Visual Studio and MSBuild too, which is where your problem is.

Comment: (Remember that VS is a .NET host, and all hosted instances of the .NET FW will log binding errors when the logger is enabled)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a missing reference. See [this post](http://blog.biztalk-info.com/archive/2008/08/15/Retrieve_the_LoaderExceptions_property_for_more_information.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunatelly cleaning and rebuilding doesn't change anything. I'm still getting the same error. This is also the only error, I'm not getting any warnings or anything about libraries that couldn't been found.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the references? I had all kinds of these problems before I started using continuous integration.

Other thing is that the build order of the projects is somehow messed up. Try building projects one by one.

Comment: I already tried that, all of my projects but one builds fine. The one that failes uses references to all the other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed MVC/ Silverlight or any other "additional" bits you are using?

It seems a project type is missing.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Yes, all additional libraries required to build my app has been installed. Also I have several projects in my solutions and only the main one doesn't build correctly. I have no problems with the others.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done somehting to your build files (*.csproj etc)? Could be that there's a target that depends on some DLL that's missing.

Comment: No I haven't, just checked out the latest sources and now I'm trying to build them.